# Interrupted windows 2008 server R2 install

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I interrupted an install of Windows 2008 server on a fast machine that was taking too long with the intentional of using an alternative boot media to the USB flash drive I was using. (It kept showing me a message saying it was preparing my computer for first time use for nearly 2 hrs). 
I therefore removed the USB drive and surprisingly it then came up with the message asking to either start in safe mode or a normal start.
I choose a normal start and it booted fine. Should I have confidence in using this as a production server or should I just go for a clean install ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming, and is primarily opinion-based.

Comment: While it "is" opinion based i think you'd get the same opinion from about everyone as soon as he said "for production". I'm not sure if it should be closed but if not it should definately be moved to serverfault as it's not about programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a "production server"? You shouldn't even be asking, don't take any risks at all and redo it, it doesn't take that long.